# absolute file upload path in expressjs

Tags: file-upload, express, relative-path, absolute-path

I can set file upload path to `/fileupload1` folder, but how to set file upload path to `/fileupload2` folder?. Thanks

```
myapp
     /config
            config.js
            express.js
            /fileupload1
     /public
            /fileupload2
     server.js
```

In `server.js` :

```
var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs'),
var app = express(),
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
exports = module.exports = app;
```

In `express.js` :

```
var express = require('express'),
module.exports = function(app, config) {
    app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: __dirname + "/fileupload1" }))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
express.bodyParser({
  keepExtensions: true,
  uploadDir     : __dirname + "/../public/fileupload2"
})
```